# lapply - assign specific value to other columns in the same row within data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have got a list with more than 100 data.frames, each one with 3 columns.

Here an example of one of the data.frames:

```
[[6]]
             V1        V2        V3
2         12002                    
9   05 Jan 1974   404.074     2.940
10  12 Jan 1974   477.433     3.235
11  18 Jan 1974   443.135     3.099
12  30 Jan 1974   556.402     3.537
13  22 Nov 1974   534.586     3.455
```

**What I desire to do is to copy the first row value on first column to the other two first row values in the other two columns.**

My result, for all the data.frames contained in the list should be:

```
[[6]]
             V1        V2        V3
2         12002     12002     12002         
9   05 Jan 1974   404.074     2.940
10  12 Jan 1974   477.433     3.235
11  18 Jan 1974   443.135     3.099
12  30 Jan 1974   556.402     3.537
13  22 Nov 1974   534.586     3.455
```

n.b. the values to copy are different for each data.frame

I tried to do it first for one data.frame (without using `lapply`) and it actually works:

```
list[[1]]$V2[1] = list[[1]]$V1[1]
```

But when I try to do it by using the `lapply` function it doesn't work anymore:

```
list = lapply(list, function(x) x$V2[1] = x$V1[1])
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: one thing to look out for is not to call your list 'list'.

Comment: thanks, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the entire df after the assignment.

```
list <- lapply(list, function(x) {
    x[1,] <- x$V1[1]
    x
}
```

Comment: that's great! I always forgot to return the df!

Answer (score 0):

same as emilliman5, here is an example

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
l <- list(d, d)
do_this <- function(dat) {
  dat[1,2] <- dat[1,1]
  return(dat)
}
lapply(l, do_this)
```